# Tape that is Safe for Paper Laminate

Tags: taping

I have cabinets that are covered with paper laminate.  I need to paint the surrounding walls.  Blue painter tape removes the color of the laminate.

What type of tape can I safely use that won't damage the laminate or remove the color?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Scotch blue masking tape for delicate surfaces? I couldn't find it on the Home Depot web site (better than it used to be but still is bad) but you can read all about it and get it from Amazon [https://www.amazon.com/ScotchBlue-Painters-Delicate-Surface-70-Inch/dp/B000BPPIL0?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duckduckgo-ffsb-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B000BPPIL0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BPPIL0)

Comment: I thought the blue painters tape was the best don't know of any thing less that would block the tape other than some heavy paper like card stock.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use a wide drywall finishing knife as a paint shield, making sure to follow your brush carefully as you cut in.

The most proficient technique I've witnessed was to put up the knife, cut in lightly, only at the knife, wipe the blade off quickly with a rag (or on your painting pants), then move the blade down to the next part of the cut in. One can get pretty quick using this method, I've seen it.

Personally, I just cut it in, no tape. Practice makes perfect.

Comment: Agreed, all tapes leave a residue or risk damage especially if left on longer and longer.... avoid it altogether and use a spreader as a paint shield

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to mask them with [frisket,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisket) a removable substance used by painters and printers to prevent ink and paint off of surfaces. You'll have to shop at an art supply store (stencil shops may be a better bet if there is one by you) rather than a hardware store, and it's going to be slightly more expensive than tape.

At least one company was marketing a masking fluid to professional painters, but I don't know the brand offhand. It can be faster and easier to mask the glass with a liquid, especially if you're spraying.